# Can I use the dynamic feature of Profile inside a MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I suspect this only applies to asp.net pages, but according to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

I can define properties in `web.config` like so:

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="PostalCode" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Then go ahead and use them like this:

```
Profile.PostalCode = txtPostalCode.Text;
```

But this does not compile for me inside a Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  Profile.PostalCode = "codeofpost";
  return View();
}
```

`Profile` is of type `ProfileBase` and not dynamic, so I've no idea how this would work, but the document says otherwise.

Comment: Did you define this property in web.config?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile class is generated only in ASP.NET Website project NOT in ASP.NET Web aplication.

In Web Application project you need to use

```
ProfielBase.GetPropertyValue(PropertyName);
```

References: http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/04/12/the-differences-in-profile-between-web-application-projects-wap-and-website.aspx

Comment: Oh I see, thanks, I've add found a way, but it doesn't give you the code completion that the website project does.

Comment: Why wouldn't you create custom class MyProfile: ProfileBase that would use properties with ProfielBase.GetPropertyValue in Get.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would be better!

Answer (score 0):

As I've been told it's not possible, I've decided to use a dynamic to do this for myself. I guess it's just syntactic sugar in the end.

Descending from this enables `Profile.PostalCode = "codeofpost";`

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a dynamic Profile.
/// </summary>
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    private readonly Lazy<DynamicProfile> _dProfile;

    protected ControllerBase()
    {
        _dProfile = new Lazy<DynamicProfile>(() => new DynamicProfile(base.Profile));
    }

    private sealed class DynamicProfile : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly ProfileBase _profile;

        public DynamicProfile(ProfileBase profile)
        {
            _profile = profile;
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            result = _profile.GetPropertyValue(binder.Name);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            _profile.SetPropertyValue(binder.Name, value);
            _profile.Save();
            return true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// New dynamic profile, can now access the properties as though they are on the Profile,
    /// e.g. Profile.PostCode
    /// </summary>
    protected new dynamic Profile
    {
        get { return _dProfile.Value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to the original profile object.
    /// </summary>
    protected ProfileBase ProfileBase
    {
        get { return base.Profile; }
    }
}
```